# Detect android application crash force close

Tags: android

I am writing an crash report application which will run as a service in background and should be able to detect other application crash, and present a user will option to report error.

So, which event should I be looking for in order to detect application crash?

ActivityManager.ProcessErrorStateInfo() class basically provides error condition. Can I use this?

Comment: Android already has something like this built-in.

Comment: Hi Robby, Can You please redirect me to the code, so i can implement the same in my application

Comment: I believe it's part of the Market app so the source isn't available.

Comment: yes Robby , right so i know its possible to do that, but now needed pointer how to do it.

Comment: I think this [link](http://code.google.com/p/android-send-me-logs/) will help you

Answer (score 5):

Check out [Crittercism](http://www.crittercism.com).  It automatically captures crashes and diagnostics for you and it's free I think.

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean something like this:

```
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() {

            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                // TODO implement this

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You might check out the [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/) application.

It's an Apache-licensed Android crash reporter. I don't think it will help you detect crashes in other applications. Incidentally, I'm not sure this is even possible.