# Can I trigger Android's built-in bug capture functionality from my app?

Tags: android, debugging, logcat, android-debug

Android has, from ICS onwards (I think) provided the ability for a user to capture the system state, and then send or share the captured data with whomever they wish. See [What does it mean with bug report captured in android tablet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648353/what-does-it-mean-with-bug-report-captured-in-android-tablet)

The captured data includes a screenshot, list of running processes, Logcat contents, active threads for each process, etc.

This is fantastically useful, but triggering it seems to involve the user pressing funny key combinations (Power + VolumeUp + VolumeDown) or enabling Developer mode and choosing specific options from there (**Take bug report**, **Power menu bug reports**).

Is there a way I can trigger this from my own code, so that I can offer my users a simple menu option to capture a bug report?

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9350486/1893766) not what you are looking for?

Comment: @shoerat No, that is about directing users to leave feedback on Google Play. I am looking for a way to invoke the specific bug-capture reporting functionality which includes system log data.

Comment: It would be nice to trigger it and get the results but I don't think there is a way to do that. It would be a bug if there is, android warn us about it after all _"Bug reports contain data from the system's various log files, including personal and private information.  Only share bug reports with apps and people you trust."_

Comment: @Onur I agree, and I would be happy for that warning to be displayed to my users! I don't want to read or store the log data in my app; I just want a way of triggering the overall process, so my users don't have to enable Developer mode or fiddle about with stupidly awkward keypress combinations.

Comment: After looking through the AOSP source, I can say that the answer to the question is *no*

Comment: Without the screenshot, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10559267/how-to-use-intent-action-app-error-as-a-means-for-a-feedback-framework-in-andr

Answer (score 2):

Reading up on the link that you have posted - [What does it mean with bug report captured in android tablet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648353/what-does-it-mean-with-bug-report-captured-in-android-tablet)

The [answer] marked as correct says `bugmailer.sh` in the `system/bin` does the reporting.

So, in theory if you could detect an app crash using any of [these methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475604/detect-android-application-crash-force-close), then you could execute your own copy of `bugmailer.sh` in the sdcard and get a report.

Source for `bugmailer.sh`: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/android-4.2.2_r1/bugmailer/bugmailer.sh

However, you will realize that this will obviously work only for rooted phones as you read the source.

The easier way would be to open the `Developer options` and have a system overlay window pointing at what they should click. This would be the only user friendly solution for non rooted phones.

You can open the `Developer options` using

```
startActivity(new Intent(
    Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DEVELOPMENT_SETTINGS));
```

For further [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way but it requires root.

What responsible of bug report is [dumpstate.c](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/master/cmds/dumpstate/dumpstate.c).

> usage: dumpstate [-b soundfile] [-e soundfile] [-o file [-d] [-p] [-z]] [-s] [-q ]
>   -o: write to file (instead of stdout)
>   -d: append date to filename (requires -o)
>   -z: gzip output (requires -o)
>   -p: capture screenshot to filename.png (requires -o)
>   -s: write output to control socket (for init)
>   -b: play sound file instead of vibrate, at beginning of job
>   -e: play sound file instead of vibrate, at end of job
>   -q: disable vibrate
>   **-B: send broadcast when finished (requires -o and -p)**

If `dumpstate` called with **`-B`** parameter, it broadcasts `"android.intent.action.BUGREPORT_FINISHED"` after that [BugreportReceiver](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/packages/Shell/src/com/android/shell/BugreportReceiver.java) handles warning the user and sharing the result.

I haven't try it but, everyone who has root privileges can call `dumpstate` like

```
dumpstate -o dump -p -B
```

to trigger it.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, users get the option to report a crash to the Google play.

There are sites that offer this functionality though, https://www.bugsense.com/ for example is easily integrated and also offers `graddle/maven` support. By using sites like these, you are sharing your data with them most likely though. That will be a trade of you have to make.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can trigger this from my own code, so that I can
>   offer my users a simple menu option to capture a bug report?

There is a library called  [**ACRA** (Application Crash Reports for Android )](https://github.com/ACRA/acra)  which allows you to send crash reports to any destinations from your own code. Developer configurable user interaction such as silent reports, Toast notification, status bar notification + dialog or direct dialog are available.

You can add your own log file extracts as well as logcat, eventlog or radiolog to reports. It's a very useful tool for crash data analysis and reports management for developers.

Also See [BasicSetup](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/BasicSetup) and [AdvancedUsage](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage).